# Nonblocking connect does not report completion to kqueue

Tags: c, macos, connect, nonblocking, kqueue

In MacOS I set up a read+write socket with `O_NONBLOCK` to connect to a remote server. I use **kqueue** to wait for and coordinate I/O events. The call to `connect()` immediately triggers `EINPROGRESS`, as it should. Soon after, the connection is completed. This is confirmed by receiving data from the server.

BUT, I thought kqueue would return a kevent when the connection finally completes and becomes writable? No such event arrives. The man page for `connect()` states:

> [EINPROGRESS] The socket is non-blocking and the connection cannot be completed immediately. It is possible to select(2) for completion by selecting the socket for writing.

(1) Does this mean I need to use `select()` instead of kqueque to receive notification of the completed connection?

(2) By the way, if I try to connect to a server where nothing is listening on the port, then kevent soon returns EOF to report there is nothing there.

(3) If I try to connect to a non-existing IP, then my kevent times out after the timeout period I have set (15 sec).

Code below. Compile, start a "server" such as `nc -l 10000`, run program with or without an IP address argument, and it will connect remotely or locally, respectively.

```c
#include <sys/event.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("socket");
    }

    int fcntl_flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
    if (fcntl_flags < 0) {
        perror("fcntl");
    }

    fcntl_flags = fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, fcntl_flags | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fcntl_flags < 0) {
        perror("fcntl");
    }

    struct sockaddr_in addr_in;
    memset(&addr_in, 0, sizeof addr_in);
    addr_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr_in.sin_port = htons(10000);
    if (!inet_pton(AF_INET, argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "127.0.0.1", &addr_in.sin_addr)) {
        perror("inet_aton");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct kevent change;
    struct kevent event;

//    Create kqueue
    int kq;
    if ((kq = kqueue()) < 0) {
        perror("kqueue");
    }

//    Set read and write on socket
    EV_SET(&change, fd, EVFILT_READ | EVFILT_WRITE, EV_ADD | EV_CLEAR, 0, 0, NULL);

//    Put socket in kqueue, return immediately
    struct timespec tmout = { 0, 0 };
    int nev = kevent(kq, &change, 1, &event, 1, &tmout);
    printf("Number events: %d (should be 0)\n", nev);

//    Connect socket to server
    if (!connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr_in, sizeof(struct sockaddr))) {
        printf("Connected\n");
    }
    else if (errno == EINPROGRESS) {
        printf("EINPROGRESS\n");
    }

//    Wait for connection to complete
    tmout.tv_sec = 15;
    nev = kevent(kq, &change, 0, &event, 1, &tmout);

    if (nev) {
        printf("Number events: %d, filter: %x, flags: %x, data: %ld\n", nev, event.filter, event.flags, event.data);
    }
    else {
        printf("Timeout\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show the code you're using to set up the kqueue and the events you're monitoring.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.

EVFILT_READ == ffffffff

EVFILT_WRITE == fffffffe

That makes EVFILT_READ | EVFILT_WRITE == EVFILT_READ

The result is that "or"-ing them together makes kqueue wait for READ events only. Flags can be "or"-ed but filters should not.