# The kqueue system call and non-blocking connect. What code should I use to test for an error in the situation?

Tags: c, sockets, freebsd, epoll, kqueue

Today, I was making small changes to my Linux code. The code is a kind of
ping-pong network program. The client writes "Hello", the server responds with
"Hello". That is all to it.

Now I use FreeBSD. So naturally `epoll` mechanism being replaced by `kqueue`.
The part of code that did a `connect` had caught my attention. The below is trimmed down code
to show how I do non-blocking `connect` with Linux.

```
n = epoll_wait (ep_fd, ep_evs, YPOLL_EPOLL_NEVENTS, timeout_ms);
/* check epoll return for errors */

/* ... */

for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) { /* service epoll events */
 sock  = (sock*)ep_evs[i].data.ptr; /* user data */
 state = sock->state; /* store socket state: paired, connecting, closed, listening */
 mask  = ep_evs[i].events;

 /* connection in progress may have errors at the very start */
 if(state != CONNECTION_IN_PROGRESS){ 
  if(mask & EPOLLHUP){ /* hang up, both read/write not possible */
   /* do something */
   continue; /* next event */
  }
  if(mask & EPOLLERR) { /* error, or pipe read end has been closed */
   /* do something */
   continue; /* next event */
  }
 }

 /* test for various events */
 /* ... */

 /* fd is a socket that is yet to be connected */
 else if((state == CONNECTION_IN_PROGRESS) && (mask & EPOLLOUT)) {
  int v = /* call getsockopt for `SO_ERROR` */
  if(v != 0){ /* connection failed */
   /* do something, maybe print error */
   continue; /* next event */
  }
  /* connection passed */
  /* maybe add the socket to the list of connected sockets ? */
  continue; /* next event */
 }

}
```

The above works for me to do a non-blocking connect to a server. With Linux.
And here I get closer to the question part. The `kqueue` interface has `flags` and `fflags`
set for the event.

The plan is to do the same with FreeBSD, so that code will do a non-blocking connect.
Do I have to call `getsockopt` to test for the error,
or I would better check for an error with `flags` and `fflags`?

**Update**

I see that the question somewhat unclear in wording. I rephrase and explain. With Linux, the only way, for me, to catch an error with a non-blocking connect, - is to call `getsockopt`, getting `SO_ERROR`. Tests for epoll masks, like `EPOLLHUP`, **does not catch all errors**. The code with `getsockopt`, is the only option for me. I had tested various setups, and the check with `SO_ERROR` does cover some error paths that epoll error reporting does not. Again, I have to admit, that the above is for my system, with my network setup, etc.

My question is, will `kqueue` set `EOF` and `fflags` in case of an error with non-blocking connect? And preferably, can I safely assume that testing for `EOF` will cover all error cases?

**Update**

Since the last write up, I've tested some code paths of an error with a non-blocking connection. The flags are set for the following: `TIMEDOUT`, `CONNRESET`, `CONNREFUSED`. I can not test all possible code paths, so I just settle for testing `EV_EOF`, for now.

Comment: Check out this question and (self-)answer. It's not completely clear but looks like it might get you well on your way. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55319444/1076479

Comment: @GilHamilton  tweak Linux code to be a FreeBSD code. From the fact - the question, maybe, stated somewhat unclear. The problem is, on my system with Linux, I have to call `getsockopt` to find out, if the were a connect error. On Linux, testing the flags did not help.

Comment: @GilHamilton I will rephrase a question, as I see it is stated in wrong words. From the above comment, my system has this case with `getsockopt` being the only way to securely test for connected socket(not counting other error tests).

Comment: @GilHamilton So I ask about does `kqueue` always, and in every case, sets `EOF` and socket error in `fflags`?